# Artifactory- can not download RPM packages from RedHat site

Tags: artifactory, rpm

I am trying to connect out JFrog Artifactory (Version 7) to Redhat as remote RPM repository, the test connection pass, but it does not manage to download.
I configured the Artifactroy to address the URL-
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7server/x86_64/os/reposdata

In the Tree Browser I can see many files there, but not repomd.xml
When I try to download a file after configuring the Linux machine to work with this Artifactroy I get-

/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 404 – Not Found

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure the URL -https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7server/x86_64/os/ as upstream URL for remote repository and follow Artifactory repository 'Set Me Up' instructions for client side configuration. According to shared error, seems changing upstream URL should fix the issue on your client side.